# Windows webserver monitor and notifier service

Tags: windows-server-2003, web-server, monitoring, iis-6

I'm looking for a software tool/service, preferably opensource/free, which will run on a Windows 2003 r3 standard server which will monitor bandwidth usage of all the websites it's hosting (a break down by site would be very useful) and also send out notifications if IIS or another service (as defined) stops responding. A web interface to see the bandwidth usage and other details would be very useful.

I've personally got a vps which does this kinda of monitoring but I believe this is more linked into the host itself.

Does anyone have any pointers?

All help is appriciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Zenoss has a VM that runs on VMware Player for Windows just fine.  Zenoss is open source and can monitor Apache or IIS (or whatever else you're using) and the network interfaces on the servers providing your websites.  It has alerts for sites going down and provides performance graphs for your interfaces and can provide graphs for your response time as well.

Comment: I wonder why there isn't a standalone Windows install? I'm just unzipping the VM image now, will let you know how it goes. Thanks for the pointer :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. For open source general process monitoring: While Nagios itself needs to run on Linux, it can also monitor Windows machines (there is a client for it).
2. For bandwidth monitoring: Any web analytics software can do that (based on your server logs). MRTG is another option.
3. For Windows service monitoring: Windows can do that itself (and restart the services). I don't think you need to monitor the IIS process itself. In all these years I never saw it crash on our many Windows servers (I guess it has built in restart features).
4. For free uptime and performance monitoring: AlertFox and Pingdom have useful free plans.